# Achieving `observe` behaviour in TensorFlow Probability

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-probability, probabilistic-programming

Consider the definition of the `observe` statement from Probabilistic Programming, as defined in [1]:

> The observe statement blocks runs which do not satisfy the boolean expression E and does not permit those executions to happen.

Now, consider the following theoretical program:

```py
def f():
    x ~ Normal(0, 1)
    observe(x > 0) # only allow samples x > 0
    return x
```

which should return values from the truncated `Normal(0, 1)` distribution.

Therefore, my question is: how can `observe` be achieved in TensorFlow Probability, or what’s its equivalent? Note that `observe`'s argument should be any (symbolic) boolean expression `E`: (e.g. `lambda x: x > 0`).

NOTE: Sure, for the program above one can use the `HalfNormal` distribution, but I am using it for a practical example of `observe`.

---

[1] Gordon, Andrew D., et al. “Probabilistic programming.” *Proceedings of the on Future of Software Engineering* . 2014. 167-181.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve this in general is using a rejection sampler, which is expensive. And then you don't have a tractable density. In general TFP requires all our distributions to have a tractable density (i.e. `dist.prob(x)`). We do have an autodiff friendly `TruncatedNormal`, or as you note `HalfNormal`.

If you wanted to implement something else it could be as simple as:

```py
class Rejection(tfd.Distribution):
  def __init__(self, underlying, condition, name=None):
    self._u = underlying
    self._c = condition
    super().__init__(dtype=underlying.dtype, 
                     name=name or f'rejection_{underlying}',
                     reparameterization_type=tfd.NOT_REPARAMETERIZED,
                     validate_args=underlying.validate_args,
                     allow_nan_stats=underlying.allow_nan_stats)
  def _batch_shape(self):
    return self._u.batch_shape
  def _batch_shape_tensor(self):
    return self._u.batch_shape_tensor()
  def _event_shape(self):
    return self._u.event_shape
  def _event_shape_tensor(self):
    return self._u.event_shape_tensor()

  def _sample_n(self, n, seed=None):
    return tf.while_loop(
        lambda samples: not tf.reduce_all(self._c(samples)),
        lambda samples: (tf.where(self._c(samples), samples, self._u.sample(n, seed=seed)),),
        (self._u.sample(n, seed=seed),))[0]

d = Rejection(tfd.Normal(0,1), lambda x: x > -.3)
s = d.sample(100).numpy()
print(s.min())
```